# Is there any last() in YUI NodeList?

Tags: javascript, yui

Let's say I try to select the last child of a list of nodes in YUI3:

```
var node = Y.one('#node');
node.all('button').last();   // pseudo-code, not actually working!
```

Is there an equivalent to jquery's `last()` (and `first()`, respectively) in YUI3?

I checked the [API docs](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/NodeList.html) and did not find anything comparable.

```
node.one('button:last-child')
```

did'nt do the job either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
one('button:last-child')
```

Should work. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GtG3Z/) example. However, `:last-child` is referring to the last child of its parent, so it is highly dependent on your DOM structure.

```
<ul>
    <li><button>Foo</button></li>
    <li><button>Bar</button></li>
    <li><button>Baz</button></li>
</ul>
<script>
Y.one('button:last-child'); // yields <button>Foo</button>
// should be written like so
Y.one('li:last-child button');
</script>
```

Comment: how could i be so blind! I'll pick your answer, @jonas-g-drange because it appears to be the most simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see one, but this appears to do the job:

```
var links=Y.all("a"),
lastLink=links.item(links.size()-1)
```

See http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/NodeList.html#method_item for more